# Return data from response within an observable in Nestjs

Tags: typescript, observable, nestjs

I'm new to [Nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com), Typescript and basically backend development. And I'm working on a simple Weather app, where I fetch weather data from [Open Weather API](https://openweathermap.org/api).
I'm using Nest built-in `HttpModule` which is wrapping Axios within, then using `HttpService` to make a GET request to Open weather. The request is returning an Observable which is totally news to me.
How do I extract the actual response data from the observable in the `Injectable service` and return it to the `Controller`?

Here's my weather.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  getWeather() {
    let obs = this.httpService.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=cairo&appid=c9661625b3eb09eed099288fbfad560a');
    
    console.log('just before subscribe');
    
    obs.subscribe((x) => {
        let {weather} = x.data;
        console.log(weather);
    })
    console.log('After subscribe');
    
    // TODO: Should extract and return response data f
    // return;
  }
}
```

And this is weather.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getWeather() {
    const res = this.appService.getWeather();
    return res;
  }
}
```

Also can someone clarify what are the missing types in my code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`RxJS Observables`](https://rxjs.dev) are essentially advanced callbacks. Because they work in an asynchronous fashion, you need to have your code deal with that. Nest can handle if an Observable is returned from the controller and will subscribe to it under the hood for you, so all you should need to do in your service is something like this:

```js
import { Injectable, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  getWeather() {
    return this.httpService.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=cairo&appid=c9661625b3eb09eed099288fbfad560a').pipe(
      map(response => response.data)
    );
   
  }
}
```

The `map` is imported from `rxjs/operators` and is similar to `Array.prototype.map` in that it can take values in and transform them as necessary. From here, your `Controller` just needs to return `this.appService.getWeather()`, and Nest will handle the rest.

The other option you have is to convert the observable to a promise using `.toPromise()` and then you can use your usual `async/await` syntax, which is another valid choice.

---

RxJS v7 and on

`toPromise()` was deprecated in RxJS v7. It's now recommended to use `lastValueFrom(observable)` or `firstValueFrom(observable)` instead to make an observable async.

Comment: Thank you, I already figured it out and did convert it `toPromise()` which made it easier to use async/await

Comment: As of mid 2022, toPromise() is deprecated.  RxJS recommends using either lastValueFrom() or firstValueFrom().
https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

Answer (score 0):

Try this to return the value,by converting the  observable to promise.

getProductList() {
return firstValueFrom(this.workflowService.getProductList()).then(res=>{return res.data});
}